# Restore accidentally deleted azure active directory profile

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have accidentally deleted my active directory profile in https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com. Of course, I can't get into my active directory as getting the message "Access denied". How I can get my deleted AD profile back? I am the account admin of this account so nobody else can provide me access. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you deleted your user profile or full ad account profile?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron AD is still there as the users I have added is still able to access it. It is just the user profile deleted. As I am the only admin nobody else can give me access as others could add me only as a guest

Comment: You can restore the deleted users within 30 days. Try that so that it can work what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

Azure active directory has the functionality to restore your user within 30 days. But after that time even [Microsoft cannot restore it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-restore?context=azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/context/ugr-context&view=azurermps-3.8.0)

**Note: If you have single admin in your active directory you cannot delete that so you might have another admin.**

**Required Permission to restore user**

- Global administrator
- Partner Tier1 Support
- Partner Tier2 Support
- User administrator

Here you can see how you can restore deleted user

**step 1**

Click on User > Deleted User now you can see all deleted users

see the screen shot below

[image]

**Step 2**

Select the user you want to restore see the screen shot below

[image]

Once you select the user click on Restore user on upper top red mark on Screen shot.

**Step 3**

Click on Yes when you have clicked on Restore user soon the process will started

see the screen shot below

[image]

**Your Case:**

You could see here no profile delete option provided. Only you could leave the organization.

see the screen shot below

[image]

**Update:**

**[Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0):**

You could add a member using [Microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0)

For more details you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-restore?context=azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/context/ugr-context&view=azurermps-3.8.0)

If you have any more query feel free to ask. Thank you.

Comment: The thing is I couldn't get into AD at all. Later one of the other users added me but he could give only guest role to me. Now when I go to AD I have only guest privileges so can't see deleted users either restore it

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan for sure your account has more admin so try to ask him to restore your account. Because a single admin cannot delete his account active directory prompt you about that you cannot delete it.

Comment: Farid - I have deleted profile here - https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/profile. It didn't warn while deleting the profile.

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan You can try to create a new user as member using graph API.